# Converting doc2vec from feed-dict to tf.data pipeline

Tags: tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to convert a [doc2vec example](https://github.com/nfmcclure/tensorflow_cookbook/tree/master/07_Natural_Language_Processing/07_Sentiment_Analysis_With_Doc2Vec) from using feed-dict to using tf.data pipeline. I am struggling how to implement the window sequence generation.

I have been successful in implementing all of the loading of data methods in [text_helpers.py](https://github.com/nfmcclure/tensorflow_cookbook/blob/master/07_Natural_Language_Processing/07_Sentiment_Analysis_With_Doc2Vec/text_helpers.py) but I cannot figure out how to tackle the `generate_batch_data` method. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

I tried to use tf.string.split to split the sentence into words, but I cannot then get the shape of the result to use to set the range to walk through `ws`.(see below) It throws an error because it is `None` and not an integer. I assume the lines to `append` the `window_sequences` variable are also not going to work.

UPDATE: Added my code to a github repo
https://github.com/waldren/doc2vec-datapipeline

UPDATE: I think I am heading in the right direction. I now have a tf.while_loop

```
   def generate_window_sequence(self, sentence_ix, sentence, label):

    ws = tf.strings.split([sentence], sep=' ').values

    offset = tf.constant(int(self.window_size/2))
    i = tf.constant(int(self.window_size/2))

    def while_condition (i, window_sequences, ws, offset):
      return tf.less(i, tf.math.subtract(tf.size(ws), offset))

    def body(i, window_sequences, ws, offset):
      #TODO - move within offset if it is > 1
      before = tf.math.subtract(i, offset)
      after = tf.math.add(i, offset)
      #window_sequences.append((tf.gather(ws, [before, i])))
      #window_sequences.append((tf.gather(ws, [after, i])))

      return i+1, window_sequences, ws, offset

    window_sequences = []
    window_sequences.append(("before1","test1"))
    i, window_sequences, ws, offset = tf.while_loop(while_condition, body, [i, window_sequences, ws, offset])

    return sentence_ix, window_sequences, label
```

This will "run" but I don't know if the loop is running multiple times. But as soon as I uncomment the two lines in the `body` function (starting with window_sequences), I get a `ValueError: Number of inputs and outputs of body must match loop_vars: 5, 7` error.

Comment: Added code to a github repo: https://github.com/waldren/doc2vec-datapipeline

Comment: Found the inspiration at this git repo: https://github.com/akb89/word2vec